# Windows 10 update activate app I have disable and resets views

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates

Every time Windows 10 64bit is updated it reactivate and reinstall apps that I have disable (like OneDrive, Alarm and Clocks and others). There is also some reset in the register since if affects the File Explorer.

Is it possible to block this behavior somehow, to not active and reinstall this builtin apps ?

To uninstall builtin app I followed this link before:
http://www.howtogeek.com/224798/how-to-uninstall-windows-10s-built-in-apps-and-how-to-reinstall-them/

Comment: Are you sure it's every update instead of just feature updates?  You can defer feature updates for 6 months if your using Windows 10 Professional.  The next feature update will offer a new feature for Windows 10 Professional allowing you to pause updates for 35 days.  If your using Windows 10 Home there isn't a way to prevent the feature updates, and only the feature updates, is what is changing your default applications.  Feature updates are also reinstall the default applications.

Answer (score 0):

This was the default behavior of Windows 10.

Beginning with the next major release this behavior will change and apps you have uninstalled will not reinstall themselves.

If you in the Insider Previews, either Slow or Fast ring, this is already fixed. Otherwise you have to wait for the "Creator's Update" later this year.